# SQL Connection string for Retail Pro Application Database

Tags: c#, database, b-tree

I am trying to make a program using c# in .net for some custom data report.

I need to do this based on a Retail Pro 8 POS Application and look forward for suggestions / help in understanding how to get the database connection.

A hint given to me was that the application uses oracle database which may not be correct.

I had not worked earlier with oracle database and I'm only familiar with MySQL and MSSQL and what makes me to doubt that the application runs on oracle database is i could easily take the dump from the client machine and run it on my machine without installing any oracle files.

So guess it may be using some kind of portable database I am unable to figure-out the database files..

some of the probable file extensions are 
*.DIA, *.DAT, *.IX

As per me Retail Pro is built on Delhi.

Any suggestions on how to access database from within my .net program would be really helpful

---

Update :
The version i am trying to work is Retail Pro 8 and this version uses B-Tree File data though now the newer version works on Oracle Database.

I was able to get Retail Pro API which has documentation on plugin creation using Delphi 5.

Now i have some clues but still don't prefer to venture out into a new prog lang just for pulling out some data from the data files.

Would appreciate if some one shows some more insight how to open these files using c#.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retail Pro V8 Comes with a rda2.dll file which can read the database and its a com dll and this can be used in vb6 but there is some issue while using the same in .net as per some documents i referred to since this was built using Delphi5.

Retail Pro also provides api which means additional two files (RPRO_API.dpk and RproAPI.pas) but these files are not provided along with the product and i myself dont have access to them. Would appreciate if some one can share this so that i can try to learn this more.

Answer (score 0):

Retail Pro POS uses a Btree structured database, so it is not possible to read or write into retail pro 8 data base directly.

If Rpro 8 database need to be accessed pragmatically special training is needed.

I am a Retail Pro certified professional with ten years of experience. If you have any requirement feel free to share with me. skpe s.chandrakumar

Comment: Thanks for the info Chandrakumar could you please provide any further help as to how do i connect to the B-Tree Data files in that case from c# ??

Comment: As I already told you, it is not a single connection string that will help you to fetch data from retail pro 8. It is a file read you need to read each fields separately from a file.Only retail pro certified technician can do it. Feel free to mail me on s.chandrakumar@gmail.com

Answer (score -2):

Hi There is readonly access to Retail Pro Database. The database for the version 9 is oracle and connection details are as follows if on the same machine else include tnames.ora for rproods and in host name put the machine name as well. 
service name is RPROODS
Default Database/User Name = reportuser; Default Password = report